# Error playing video using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback; assembly version error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, directx, audiovideoplayback

I am trying to embed video on c# windows form based application, using assembly ***Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback*** but getting following error

```
Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 .NET version 4.0
Microsoft DirectX SDK is also installed
Any link for updated version of library or any alternative?

Code:

```
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;
namespace MathBook
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Video vd;
        public Form1()
        { InitializeComponent(); }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                vd = new Video(@"absolute_file_location.wmv", true);
                vd.Owner = panel1;
                vd.Play();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as error message says you need additional configuration information.

set [`useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx) as `true` in your app config file

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Damith: I am trying your solution.

Comment: Issue resolved, with your solution. Thank you so much once again for that help.

For future reference there were two more problems in my code.
1. I was not catching any exception
2. I was using .flv which is not supported using .wmv file worked perfect.